# Can a class have 2 attributes of which only 1 can be filled?

Tags: c#, class

I have a class called `Person`, and a person can either be a `Student` or a `Teacher`.

The `Person` class contains basic attributes like the name, the birthdate and the emailaddress.

The `Teacher` class contains attributes like the teachernumber, the date they joined the school and the subject they teach.

The `Student` contains attributes like the studentnumber, the current class theyre in and an average grade.

Both `Teacher` and `Student` should inherit the attributes `Person` has. Normally I would give the `Teacher` and `Student` an attribute linked to the `Person`, but this isnt gonna work this time.

I need to be able to create a `Person` object and use it with other classes and a `Person` can only be either `Teacher` or `Student`. If there is another way, let me know.

What Im thinking is something like this, but I dont know if there is a way:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    //Like this
    public Teacher T { get; set; } || public Student S { get; set; }
}
```

And then I could declare it like this:

```
//For teacher
Person person = new Person(1, "Hans", "Klok", "0636257135", new Teacher(attributes here)));

//For student
Person person = new Person(1, "Hans", "Klok", "0636257135", new Student(attributes here)));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have the set methods overwrite or null the other attribute when called

Comment: How would that look in code?

Comment: Normally, you would use inheritance for this, not generics: `class Teacher: Person {...}; class Student: Person {};`.

Comment: Another vote for inheritance being the right solution here.  I.e. a Student and Teacher are both a Person.  Which means you can do:  
Person person = new Teacher(1, "Hans", "Klok", "0636257135, teacher attributes here);
Person person = new Student(1, "Hans", "Klok", "0636257135, student attributes here);

Answer (score 1):

If you want a class to inherit properties of another class you should use inheritance, assuming you are not representing SQL tables.

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

class Teacher : Person
{
    // Teacher specific props
}

class Student : Person
{
    // Teacher specific props
}
```

call it with

```
Student person = new Student(1, "Hans", "Klok", "0636257135"); //assuming you added constructor;
```

If you wanted to represent 1-1 relationships using EntityFramework, one way would be to have PersonId's on the Teacher and Student models. Then using EntityFramework's fluent API, put a unique constraint on PeopleId.

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    // Teacher specific props
}

class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId{ get; set; }
    // Teacher specific props
}
```